# Open a Workbook and Run a Macro From Another - Delphi 2010

Tags: excel, delphi, delphi-2010

I'm trying to open a Excel workbook and run a macro in it, but the macro is localized in another workbook, like this:

```
Excel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
Excel.Workbooks.Open('C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\MyDocs\2013\JUN\andrade 1670930.xml');

Excel.Run('C:\Configura_Xml.xls!Configura_XML_Geral');
Excel.Quit;
```

But this code doesn't work because the syntax for running a macro is:

```
"'C:\Name_Of_Book'!Name_of_Macro"
```

How do I do it in Delphi?

Comment: I found a alternative: `Excel.run(#39+'C:\Configura_Xml.xls'+#39+'!Configura_XML_Geral');`

Comment: Or use `Excel.Run('''C:\Configura_Xml.xls''!Configura_XML_Geral');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question boils down to this:

> How do I specify a single quote character in a Delphi string?

You do that by escaping the quote like this:

```
''
```

So, to specify a string containing a single quote surrounded by spaces, say, you write this:

```
str := ' '' ';
```

To run your macro you quote it like this:

```
Excel.Run('''C:\Configura_Xml.xls''!Configura_XML_Geral');
```

The full details can be found in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements).